# How to debug app crashing on macOS Sierra at [[_NSCGSWindowBuffer colorSpace] retain]

Tags: macos, crash, segmentation-fault, webkit, macos-sierra

I distribute an app through the Mac App Store. With the upgrade to macOS Sierra (10.12 & 10.12.1), a lot of my users see the app crashing at seemingly random times.

I've not been able to reproduce this myself, but it is affecting a lot of users. I suspect that a change in macOS Sierra is causing this, because the app works fine on older versions of Mac OS X.

How can I go about debugging this when the crash is deep in AppKit?

Here's what I have/know:

- Document-based Mac app built on Mac OS X 10.11 (Xcode 7.2)
- Works fine on 10.11 and before, crashes at random times on 10.12 and 10.12.1
- It uses an embedded WebView
- Cause is each time: `objc_msgSend() selector name: retain` at `-[_NSCGSWindowBuffer colorSpace]`
- All crash logs show references to `com.apple.JavaScriptCore` in stack traces of other threads
- Some users said they used the app in full-screen or split-view mode when it crashed

Looking at the stack trace, could this be an issue in WebKit or is this a coincidence, because my app happens to include an embedded WebView?

I thought about adding more logging statements to the app and give a special debug version to a few users. Is there something I could log or watch out for to figure out what is causing this?

At this point, I'm thankful for any and all suggestions...

**EDIT:**

*One other developer running into the same issue got in touch with me. If you are seeing the same problem, please let me know so that we can compare notes and hopefully spot a pattern.*

**Crash log** (excerpt):

```
    Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

    Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00002a955ae2bec0
    Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

    Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
    Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
    Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

    VM Regions Near 0x2a955ae2bec0:
        JS JIT generated code  000026d481e01000-000026d481e02000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  
    --> 
        MALLOC_NANO            0000600000000000-0000600002400000 [ 36.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

    Application Specific Information:
    objc_msgSend() selector name: retain


    Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fffa66d8b5d objc_msgSend + 29
    1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fc86b71 -[_NSCGSWindowBuffer colorSpace] + 33
    2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fc5b5ad __NSCGSWindowBackingStoreMark__block_invoke + 997
    3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fc1eba3 NSCGSTransactionRunPreCommitActionsForOrder_ + 289
    4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fc1ea6f NSCGSTransactionRunPreCommitActions_ + 31
    5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fc1ea44 __39+[_NSCGSTransaction currentTransaction]_block_invoke + 34
    6   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff979921ba CA::Transaction::run_commit_handlers(CATransactionPhase) + 46
    7   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff97a9a12f CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 959
    8   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff97990d55 CA::Transaction::commit() + 475
    9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ff00c69 __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke.31 + 323
    10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff91e75ec7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff91e75e37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff91e56d79 __CFRunLoopRun + 873
    13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff91e567b4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff913f2fbc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
    15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff913f2cf9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 184
    16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff913f2c26 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
    17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fadcb79 _DPSNextEvent + 1093
    18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff901f21c3 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1637
    19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fad153d -[NSApplication run] + 926
    20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8fa9c1ad NSApplicationMain + 1237
    21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffa6fc3255 start + 1

    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffa70f1fde __semwait_signal + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fffa7078b72 nanosleep + 199
    2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fffa5ba865b std::__1::this_thread::sleep_for(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > const&) + 80
    3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff94ccb3df void std::__1::this_thread::sleep_for<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> > const&) + 63
    4   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff94cca3d1 bmalloc::waitUntilFalse(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >, bool&) + 113
    5   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff94cca220 bmalloc::Heap::scavenge(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >) + 48
    6   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff94cca0b4 bmalloc::Heap::concurrentScavenge() + 68
    7   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff94ccb621 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 97
    8   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff94ccb529 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*) + 9
    9   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff94ccb7dd void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >(void*) + 93
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffa71daaab _pthread_body + 180
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffa71da9f7 _pthread_start + 286
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffa71da221 thread_start + 13

[...]
```